# Need help in logic building for react table

Tags: reactjs, logic, react-component

I have a very little problem, but I am new developer and learning react for the very first time, finding it very hard to solve it.

Problem:

I have a component named Table, I am rendering another component named TableRow inside this by iterating over other items. In table row component I am rendering rows. I have data rows something like this:

```
1: [a]
2: [a,b]
3: [a]
```

I want output something like this

```
1  a
2  a
   b
3  a
```

I am able to achieve output like this

```
1  a
2  a
2  b
3  a
```

but finding it very hard to get the exact output. In table row component, I am just iterating over items and displaying it, I have to include a login in which I can check if header for 2 is already available, don't put it, and insert only data part. How to achieve that. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

```
data: [
{
  header: header
  items: [1]
},
{
   header: header2,
   items: [1,2]
 },
{
   header: header3,
    items: [1,2]
 }
 ]
```

SampleCode:

```
<Table>
    this.props.data.map(obj => {
        return <NewComponent header = {obj.header} items = {obj.items} />
    })
</Table>

<NewComponent> 
    this.props.items.map(item=> {
        <TableRow> 
                <th> {this.props.header} </th>
                <tb> {item} </tb>
        </TableRow>
    })
</NewComponent>
```

Current Output:

```
1 1
2 1
2 2 
3 1
```

I want

```
1  1
2  1
   2
3  1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `this.props.header` is that the first column?

Comment: yes this is the first column. @JohnRuddell

Comment: then how does it change from 1 to 2 to 3? its not coming from the `item` that you're mapping.

Comment: Oh nvm it comes from the parent mapping. table is rendered multiple times.. got it.

Comment: Please provide an example of headers, this.props.items and this.props.header in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just conditionally render the header value if its the first pass

```
<Table>
    this.props.items.map( (item, idx), => 
        <TableRow> 
            <TableHeader>{idx === 0 ? this.props.header : ''}<TableHeader>
            <TableBody>body>item<TableBody>
        </TableRow>
    )
</Table>
```

#### Edit

heres an example following your update.

```
const Table = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((row, idx) => (
            <TableRow header={row.header} items={row.items} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const TableRow = ({ header, items }) => {
  return items.map((item, idx) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{idx === 0 ? header : " "}</td>
      <td>{item}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
};
```

[Heres a simple example to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-32m65)

Comment: Hi @johnRuddel I am sorry I think I was not able to explain it correctly. I have posted it again which help you better understand. Your approach is good but this will create three tables. (referring to example)

Comment: Sure, in my example i put in tables because I dont know what elements you're using for `Table` `TableRow`... etc. but the code that is here is the same as in your question except the conditional I added `idx === 0 ? this.props.header : ''`

Comment: Ah you just changed the code, gotcha. thats fine, just move the table element outside of the row component then.

Comment: Didn't get you sorry I am new. :) @johnRuddell

Comment: @SagarKumar like this. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-32m65. Just render a row instead of a table.

Comment: Haha happy to help :) let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you again. this is exactly what I wanted.